# Better way to forward fill a DataFrame/array with calculations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame (or numpy 2D array, if you please) like so:

```
                    0       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
tstamp                                                                                  
2016-09-19 00:00:00 29.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-09-19 00:01:00 29.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-09-19 00:02:00 29.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-09-19 00:03:00 29.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2016-09-19 00:04:00 29.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I need to fill all `NaN` with this:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    df.loc[:, i] = const + df.loc[:, i-1].multiply(const)
```

Where `const` is some constant. Now, obviously the first thing that comes to mind is to use slices:

```
df.loc[:, 1:] = const + df.loc[:, :-1].multiply(const)
```

But note that the value of the next column depends on the **computed** value of the previous column. Is there a way to do this outside the loop?

---

Ps., although this is totally unnecessary, but:

```
df.loc[row_slice, col_slice].values
```

will return a `numpy NDArray` of the sliced frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.ones((5, 10), dtype=int) * 29,
    index=pd.date_range('2016-09-19', periods=5, freq='H'),
    columns=range(10))

df
```

[image]

---

***solution***

```
constant = 2
p = np.power(constant, np.arange(1, df.values.shape[1]))
df.iloc[:, 1:] = p * (1 + df.values[:, [0]]) + np.append(0, p[:-1].cumsum())

df
```

[image]

Comment: I knew you wouldn't disappoint! An excellent hack of the `power` function to do this. I have 3 more implementations in `numpy`, but I never thought of using `power`...

Comment: Actually, because, I asked the simplest model I have, and looking at it in isolation, `power` is the most natural choice. For some other more complex ones, constant is not so straightforward, it is actually the model coefficient, and can be different. I'll play around with this some more tomorrow...

Comment: I can't guarantee I'll have time to look at it, but I always welcome a challenge.  I'll try to look out for another model.

Comment: The models may also use more than one column. It is ARIMA, actually... So depending on the order, more than the immediate previous column would be used. Worst is ARIMA(2,2,q), which requires 4 previous columns, each with it's own coefficient, and a possible drift term...

Comment: Ha! I have 54 models! Well, 48 if you discount the naive ones... I was on a de-looping spree all day today, and thought I might gather some more ideas here. Hence I posted the simplest model I have, to see if there are ways other than what I have considered. Wasn't very hopeful, but you did prove me wrong there!